# Confidence Interval of Correlation Coefficient

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $\mathbf{X}$ be distributed as $N_3(0,\mathbf{\Sigma})$ where $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ has unit variances and correlation coefficient $\rho$. Given an observation $(x_1, x_2, x_3)^{'}$, obtain a confidence interval for $\rho$ with confidence coefficient $(1-\alpha)$.

$\mathbf{Proof}$

Since $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ has unit variances we have that $\rho_{xy}=\frac{\sigma_{xy}}{\sigma_{xx}\sigma_{yy}}=\sigma_{xy}$. This means $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is of the form:

$$\mathbf{\Sigma}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \rho & \rho \\ \rho & 1 & \rho \\
\rho & \rho & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\mathbf{X} \sim N_3(0,\mathbf{\Sigma}) \implies \mathbf{1}^{'}\mathbf{X} \sim N_1(\mathbf{1}^{'} \mathbf{0},\mathbf{1}^{'} \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{1})$$

$\mathbf{1}^{'} \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \rho & \rho \\ \rho & 1 & \rho \\ \rho & \rho & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 + 2\rho & 1 + 2 \rho & 1 + 2 \rho \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}=3 + 6 \rho$

$$\implies \mathbf{1}^{'}\mathbf{X} \sim N(0, 3 + 6 \rho) \implies \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 X_i-0}{\sqrt{3+6 \rho}} \sim N(0,1)$$

In the text we have the following formula for finding the confidence region for the mean vector $\mathbf{\mu}$:

$$P\Big[n(\mathbf{\overline{X}}-\mathbf{\mu})^{'}\mathbf{S}^{-1}(\mathbf{\overline{X}}-\mathbf{\mu})\leq \frac{(n-1)p}{n-p}F_{p,n-p}(\alpha)\Big]=1-\alpha$$

where $F_{p,n-p}$ denotes a random variable with an F-distribution with p and n-p degrees of freedom. How can I use this formula, along with the expression I have derived thus far to find a confidence region for a correlation coefficient instead of the mean vector $\mu$?

Comment: All you need is a pivot. You already have $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^3 X_i}{\sqrt{3+6\rho}}\sim N(0,1)$. Or you can square this to have a $\chi^2_1$ distribution. If $\Sigma$ is nonsingular, then another pivot could be $X^T\Sigma^{-1}X\sim \chi^2_3$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Just a quick question. If $X\sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$ is multivariate normal and $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is non zero and contant, is it true that $$a^TX\sim N(a^T \mu, a^T \Sigma a)?$$

Comment: @MatthewPilling It is true.

Comment: @StubbornAtom that is awesome! Never knew that. I also never knew one could estimate the population correlation coefficient off of a single observation.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Can you help me understand what a pivot is? And how it is used for finding a confidence interval?